# 'createConsumer' is not exported by node_modules/@rails/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rollupjs

I'm trying to import `createConsumer` from actioncable in the following script. https://github.com/jonathan-s/sockpuppet/blob/stimulus/javascript/stimulus/consumer.js#L1

When I try to build it with rollup.js it all fails with the following error.

```
[!] Error: 'createConsumer' is not exported by 
node_modules/@rails/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable.js, 
imported by javascript/stimulus/consumer.js
```

When I take a look at node_modules, it does look like `action_cable.js` is exporting `createConsumer` so I'm unsure of what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

What made the error go away was to use commonjs with named exports.

```
plugins: [
    commonjs({
        namedExports: {
            "node_modules/@rails/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable.js": ["createConsumer"]
        }
    }),
]
```

Comment: This does not work any more: `(!) Plugin commonjs: The namedExports option from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs" is deprecated. Named exports are now handled automatically.` says rollup. But despite working, it fails with the same error again...

Comment: The problem seems to be that action_cable.js is in CJS format, and rollup does not properly detect the `createConsumer` named export...

Comment: Correction. action_cable.js is in UMD format. rebuilding it in ESM solves the problem.